# Is there a Palm OS-style launcher (placing apps in categories)?

Tags: launcher

I am interested in a launcher/home screen application which behaves like the classic Palm OS (not WebOS) launcher. Specifically, *every* installed application is in exactly one *category*, and you can flip between categories. There is no separate app drawer versus home-screen. Ideally, I could reorganize the apps (and add shortcuts and widgets) within each category, and let the less-used part of that category be accessible by scrolling past the 'bottom' of the screen.

(I get the impression that iOS (and so iOS-inspired Android launchers, presumably) does a similar thing of forcing each application to be on some page of the home screen, but I specifically want to have single categories larger than my screen size; e.g. "Games".)

My goal is to make it harder to forget I have an app — because the standard app drawer is a big unorganized list, I hardly ever look at it, and when installing inessential things like games it's easy to forget to carefully add it to a folder.

I would also like it to not have extra features which require extra permissions (widgets can check my calendar for me, thanks).

---

I am currently using folders to organize my apps into categories (in the stock Android launcher), but this is an moderately unsatisfactory solution:

- There is no “Uncategorized” folder which newly installed apps or *apps removed from other locations* end up in.
- I would like the “rest of the category” to be more naturally “connected” to the home screen (e.g. scrolling down) rather than being a single icon on it.
- I would like to have more than five categories.
- There is [a bug in the stock launcher](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10667) in which the use of folders causes other home screen slots to misbehave.

Comment: Folders do all this apart from automatic categorization, which isn't possible without metadata that I don't believe is provided by the Market.  Are you looking for a way to have all newly installed apps put in an "Uncategorized" folder?

Comment: Yes. I’ve added details about folders to my question.

Comment: I just released TinyLaunch, which is a tiny PalmOS-style launcher that shows a categorizable list of apps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps the launcher from the miui rom will do what you need- it supports folders, there is no app drawer, and you can pinch to zoom out and quickly change home screens. Most other 3rd party launchers (adw, launcher pro, my personal favorite go launcher ex) do the same things but keep the app drawer.

Comment: Can MIUI's launcher be used without installing a custom ROM? Do the third-party launchers you mention have the "always in at least one category/folder" feature?

Comment: yes, go launcher does this in a way- there are folders inside the app drawer (pretty much identical to the iphone's home screen). install it and experiment to find out, works better than describing it. <br>
Also, this might work https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher.miui&feature=search_result